# How to extract auth0 Token from URL in ui.router

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, auth0

I've got an angular1 Application which uses auth0.js to authenticate.
I want to store the token in my tokenService when my app is recieving the callback from auth0.

https://localhost:44316/Run#access_token=ufgdfgfdNCRfYBP&expires_in=86400&id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Ryb2JsZXIuZXUuYXV0gDfgAuY29tLyIsInN1fgf6Imdvb2dsZS1vYXV0aDJ8MTAzOTAwNjAwNjI0MTg2MTIyMDAwIiwiYXVkIjoieU1XYUt3VmF1ckhsaU5hemZVM3c0QUtzV2hXVEFJSHIiLCJleHAiOjE0OTM0ODk0MDgsImlhdCI6MTQ5MzQ1MzQwOH0.NuRxvsOIoB5_zZLl5aZd7zYgAhXxpvEhXXDJ1dkurRo&token_type=Bearer

How can i create an ui.router state matching the url so that my resolve can 
proccess the request and fetch additional data?

```
$stateProvider
        .state('RecieveAuth', {
            url: "",
            resolve: tokenresolve,
            controller: function($tate){
                $state.go("MainSite");
            },
            data: { requirelanguage: true, requireLogin: true },

        })
```

does not work, And if i use "/" as an url it does not match "#accesstoken="

I already tried to do the processing in run, but in this version i don't know how to keep the controllers waiting until my http call completed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround using an injector:

```
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
        var state = $injector.get('$state');
        var $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
        var accountSvc = $injector.get("accountSvc");
        var tokenService = $injector.get("tokenService");

        console.log('location', $location, 'location.search()', $location.search());

        if ($location.$$url.indexOf('/access_token=') >= 0) {
            accountSvc.authenticateAndGetProfile(function () {
                tokenService.Reload();
                $rootScope.Authenticate();
                state.go('Folders');
            }, function () {
                state.go('Folders');

            });
        }
        return $location.path();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your resolve function, call a service from whatever factory for instance (where Data is a factory):

```
$stateProvider
    .state('RecieveAuth', {
        url: "",
        resolve: {
            content: function(Data) {
                return Data.isAuth()
            }
        },
        controller: function($tate){
            $state.go("MainSite");
        },
        data: { requirelanguage: true, requireLogin: true },

    })
```

And in your Data Factory, the isAuth() function can look like:

```
let isAuth = function() {
    // Get Token from URL or local storage
    let urlParameters = $location.search();
    let token = '';

    if ( urlParameters.hasOwnProperty('accesstoken') ) {
      tokenSurvey = urlParameters['accesstoken'];
    }

    let deferred = $q.defer();
    $resource('Call your server with the token retrieved above').query().$promise.then( (data) => {
        //User successfully, auth, rreturn resolve promise
        deferred.resolve(data);
      },
      (error) => {
        // Eror during Auth, reject promise, state will not be loaded (you have to handle errors in this case)
        deferred.reject(error);
      });
    return deferred.promise;
  };
```